# how to create custom conditon hook for loging to wordpress account

Tags: php

I'm trying to check user level for redirect wp-admin page or site dashboard page when user log in to a word press site. Please any one can give me a working code for that

Comment: @andyroo that doesn't actually check if the user is admin, it checks if its the dashboard or admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the current user is an admin you can use:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    /* A user with admin privileges */
} else {
    /* A user without admin privileges */
}
```